# Updating objects on parse - [Error] object not found

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to update an object on Parse, however i get the error message:
[Error]: object not found for update (Code: 101)

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Answers")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if let objects = objects {
            for object in objects {
                    object["upVoters"] = ["one","two"]
                    object.saveInBackground()
            }
        }
    }
```

What is causing this, and how do i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this issue is to do with the ACL settings of the object i was trying to edit. I was trying to edit an object that wasn't created by me, and the ACL did not have public write access as true. See [Parse ACL](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.ACL.html#methods)